# installing ipa from some website to computer ( Macbook ) direct as ipa

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa

How can I install an iPhone app from some website to MacBook direct as IPA?

since when I click to download the iPhone app from some website will not work only when I open this link in iPhone, after I open the link from iPhone will start directly downloading without asking about my apple email, after downloading the app in iPhone and I tried to open it they ask only to trust this app then will be work on iPhone like any apple store apps.

My question now, How can I download this app directly to MacBook as IPA ??

Answer (score 1):

The download link should look like this:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

You need to copy the whole text after `url=` to some URLDecode website(there are plenty of them in Google). And decode it. Then you will see the real url. You can open it in your browser.

It's a plist file(some may not have the `.plist` Suffix).
You can edit with any text editor. Or just open it in your browser. The real url of ipa file is inside the plist file, just like this
[plist file sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBVV4.png).

Comment: Thank You So Much its really helpful